How to make ts-jest supports static initialization blocks syntax?
Test suite failed while the code includes static initialization blocks.
class Model {
    static {
        this.schema.index( {} );
    }
}

● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'schema')

      23 |
      24 |     static {
    > 25 |         this.schema.index( {
         |              ^
      26 |             groups : -1
      27 |         } );
      28 |

and this is my jest config:
module.exports = {

    cacheDirectory : `${__dirname}/.jest-cache`,
    preset : 'ts-jest',
    // setupFilesAfterEnv : [ 'jest-extended/all' ],
    testMatch : [
        '**/test/**/*.spec.[tj]s?(x)',
        '**/test/**/*.dt.ts'
    ],

    // Indicates which provider should be used to instrument code for coverage
    coverageProvider : 'v8',

    // A list of reporter names that jest uses when writing coverage reports
    coverageReporters : [
        'json',
        'text-summary',
        'text',
        'lcov',
        'clover'
    ],
    collectCoverageFrom : [
        '**/src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        '**/scripts/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        '!**/*.d.ts'
    ],
    testEnvironment : 'node',
    transform : {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$' : [
            'ts-jest',
            {
                isolatedModules : true,
                tsconfig : '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json'
            }
        ]
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns : [
        '\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$'
    ]
}

I tried changing compile target in tsconfig.json, but it didn't work.
